# Read Microsoft Excel data without using OLEDB provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Excel file with header and few data ,i have to read Excel file without using oledb provider because i need to install oledb provider on server so i don't have a permission. Is there any alternative solution.

is it possible to read excel file using pure .net framework? if possible then what are the ways to read Excel file.

Comment: Do you have permissions to read the Excel file?

Comment: yes i have permissions to read the excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to read and write Excel files without OLEDB or Office installed:

> EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files
>   using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

Comment: @Vishal: Yes. If the file was created with version 2007 or later, you can unzip it and then read the xml data. But, of course, that's very uncomfortable.

Comment: @Vishal: you asked "Read Microsoft Excel data without using OLEDB provider?" - I've told you how to do that. It's neither helpful or good form to then add extra constraints in comments.